# TFS 2013 download build log

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Is there a way to download specific TFS build log? we’re using TFS 2013.

I’ve already tried to use the IBuildDetail, yet failed.

THX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the menthod “Get Build”. It returns IBuildDetail , use IBuildDetail.LogLocation property to get the log file for this build. Finally download or query it. Below is a  demo code:

```
publicstaticvoid GetBuildLogAndReadThroughTheLog()
  {
      // Get all the team projects using the TFS API
      var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TfsUri"]));
      var versionControlService = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
      var teamProject = versionControlService.GetAllTeamProjects(false)[0];
      // Use the build service to get build details for a team project
      var buildService = tfs.GetService<IBuildServer>();
      // Get the build details
      var build = buildService.QueryBuilds(teamProject.Name)[0];
      // Get the location of the build Log
      var buildLogLocation = build.LogLocation;
      // Get the log file
      var logFile = versionControlService.GetItem(buildLogLocation);
      // Do you want to download the file to a local path?
      TextReader tr = new StreamReader(logFile.DownloadFile());
      string input = null;
      while ((input = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        }
    }
  }
```

The entire build log can be found in the Tfs_YourTeamProjectCollection database in the Tbl_BuildInformation. You can also query and get it from DataBase
More ways for you reference: https://paulselles.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/tfs-build-log-querying-build-log-data/

**UPdate**

Using  "StreamReader" will read the log file line by line.

```
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(buildLogLocation)
 { 
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
            {
                // do your work here...
            } 
  }
```

Comment: Hi Patrick and thanks for youre response. When trying to use the code, the line :       var logFile = versionControlService.GetItem(buildLogLocation); raises exception. Any idea why?

Comment: Which exception did you get?Have you connect to TFS via programmatically  successful ?There are many blogs about it in google.

Comment: Yes the connection to TFS is successful and I can see various information about the build. Yet, when code reaches var logFile = versionControlService.GetItem(buildLogLocation);  ItemNotMappetException which is raised. Please note that buildLogLocation =  "#/29007/logs".

Comment: The reason why you get ItemNotMappedException is because your log path is not mapped to a workspace in TFS. For example, "$/Log" path from TFS is mapped to "C:\TFS\Log" location and then if you use VersionControlService from TFS API within "C:\TFS\log" location then it will work. But anything outside of "C:\TFS\Log" location (which is not known to TFS via workspace mapping) is not accessible / usable via VersionControlService. So you may need add your build log location to TFS Version Control first and check in files. If you don't want do it, try to use "streamreader " Updated my reply.

Comment: Must possible that you are right, sine I don’t know how to map this path. Can you please instruct how to?

Comment: You should set you build output locatiion to a mapping folder , there is a configuation in build definition called As configued. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654495/tfs-build-content-output-directory/33668048#33668048  Then you can use scripts in your build process  to copy to a folder. A sample script  from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353(v=vs.120).aspx (Sorry, never test) Hmm, I think i found a better way to meet your needs.