# tfs build content output directory

Tags: tfsbuild

I have the following scenario:

- A C# Class library
- TFS build 2012

In the project i have the following structure:

```
-Resources
---File.extension (type: content, copy always)
```

When I build this localy with visual studio I get the following:

```
bin\resources\File.extension
```

This is what I want and expect, but on the tfs build I get the following:

```
bin\File.extension
```

I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening. 
I would like to know why this could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the **Build Output Location** in your Build Process→Build→Outputlocation. The **default value is SingleFolder**, this is why you got this. To achieve what you want, you can change it AsConfigured.
[image]

To control where the TFBuild places the build outputs, choose:

**• SingleFolder** ：to place all the build output files together in the drop folder.

**• PerProject** ：to group the build outputs into drop folder sub-folders for each solution or code project that you have specified in the Projects box.

**• AsConfigured** ：to leave the binaries in the build agent sources folder, organized into the same sub-folder structure you see when you build your code on your dev machine in Visual Studio. This structure is defined in your code projects.

Comment: The 'Output Location' - 'AsConfigured' setting is available in TFS2013. For  TFS2012, it is needed to modify the build process template to customize the output folder. See: https://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/customize-binaries-folder-in-tfs-team-build-part-2/